# ChipWidget not updating onTap

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, layout

I'm facing a problem my Chip is not updating when I type only when I change of page or reload it.

Here is my code

```
.
.
.

late final FiltersProvider filtersProvider;
.
.
.
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          filtersProvider.setReject();
        },
        child: Chip(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          backgroundColor: filtersProvider.isApproved
              ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
              : Colors.grey[200],
          label: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              if (filtersProvider.isApproved)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.done,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              Text(
                "music speaks",
                textScaleFactor: 1,
                style: _textStyle(context, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),


.
.
.
 TextStyle _textStyle(BuildContext context,
          {FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeight.normal}) =>
      TextStyle(
        color:
            isSelected ? Colors.white : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        fontWeight: fontWeight,
      );
```

The method onTap() is not updating my variable bool filtersProvider.
I hope you can help me :)

Solving my problem, and give me a feedback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem? does onTap not trigger? Try setting a breakpoint and verify it...

If your widget is not updating, you will have to call setState... (if the widget is stateful)

Instead of using a Gesture Detector on a Chip, you can look into ActionChip, which has an onPressed() callback. Will make things a bit easier.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ActionChip-class.html

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do all changes. But if I use setState method I got an error "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.", I would like a visual feedBack when I tap the chip the chip will be selected changing its color.